# Disable table row checkbox conditionally using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to disable select checkbox in the row conditionally. If the File_Status is "IN", the checkbox select must be Enabled else Disabled. How can i achieve this using jquery. Stuck, Need help

```
<table id="Infiletbl" class="table table-responsive table-hover">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Select</th>
                        <th>Dept_Code</th>
                        <th>File_Code</th>
                        <th>Carton_Code</th>
                        <th>File_Status</th>
                        <th>Dept_File_ID</th>


                    </tr>
                    <tbody>
                        @if (ViewBag.Infilelist != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var item in ViewBag.Infilelist)
                        {
                    <tr>
                        <td><input id="reqflchk" name="filerequestfc" type="checkbox" class="chkCheckBoxId" value="@item.FileIN_ID"  /></td>
@Html.Raw(@item.File_Status == "IN" ? "disabled" : "")


                        <td>@item.Dept_Code</td>
                        <td>@item.File_Code</td>
                        <td>@item.Carton_Code</td>
                        <td>@item.File_Status</td>
                        <td>@item.Dept_File_ID</td>



                    </tr>


                        }
                    }
                    </tbody>

                </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

was able to disable the checkboxes with the following code

```
<input id="reqflchk" type="checkbox" @(item.File_Status != "Retrieval-Processed" ? " disabled='disabled'" : null) value="@item.FileIN_ID" name="filerequestfc" hidden="hidden" checked="checked" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is razor, add below to your input tag with type checkbox.

@Html.Raw(@item.File_Status == "IN"? "disabled" : "")